# Where can I find sources that could help me write about parody of human feelings in Beckett's novel "Molloy"?

Tags: french-language, literary-device, samuel-beckett, molloy

My college assignment is to write about parody in Beckett's *Molloy* and I need to write about the parody of human feelings in this novel too. I would appreciate if someone could tell me which sources and bibliography to use.
I'm reading *Molloy* in the English translation. Only English language is OK for secondary sources. I could not find relevant sources anywhere. I searched Google Books, Google Scholar and JSTOR.

Comment: You can advanced search Worldcat filtering for reference materials, I’m pretty sure they index encyclopedia articles, not just encyclopedias. Those reference materials may include bibliographies of other recommended reference materials. This way you can get a sense of an overview of the available literature and decide which works appeal to you the most.

Answer (score 4):

For a bibliography about Beckett and his works, you can refer to [*The Grove Companion to Samuel Beckett: A Reader's Guide to His Work, Life, and Thought*](https://groveatlantic.com/book/the-grove-companion-to-samuel-beckett/) by C.J. Ackerley and Stanley Gontarski (Grove Press, 2004). It has an extensive bibliography at the end of the book. (I assume the same book is available in the UK as [*The Faber Companion to Samuel Beckett*](https://www.faber.co.uk/9780571227389-the-faber-companion-to-samuel-beckett.html).)

I have not been able to find publications specifically about Beckett's parody of human feelings in *Molloy*, so I think one should make sure to understand what is meant be that based on other studies about Beckett's work and then go back to *Molloy* to detect examples of it in that novel. For example, page 148 in [*astiches, Parodies & Other Immitations*](https://books.google.de/books?id=8NRfPa20It8C&pg=PA149&dq=parody+of+feelings&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYq6rul9jrAhVNmqQKHStYA3oQuwUwAHoECAAQBg#v=onepage&q=parody%20feelings&f=false), edited by Marius Buning, Matthijs Engelberts and Sjef Houppermans (Rodopi 2002), points out that Beckett's story "Yellow" "appears to parody our notions of suffering, sympathy and 'human feeling'". (The context is a discussion of how Beckett appears to use allusions to Shakepeare's *The Tempest* in a parodic way.)

[*Samuel Beckett: A Collection of Critical Essays*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/samuel-beckett-a-collection-of-critical-essays/oclc/307098), edited by Martin Esslin (Prentice-Hall, 1965) contains the essay "Samuel Beckett and Universal Parody" by Jean-Jacques Mayoux.

[*A Companion to Samuel Beckett*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/companion-to-samuel-beckett/oclc/854470218), edited by S. E. Gontarski (Wiley-Blackwell, 2010) contains the essay "*Molloy*, or Life without a Chambermaid" by Patrick A. McCarthy (chapter 18, pages 263-274).

[*The New Cambridge Companion to Samuel Beckett*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/new-cambridge-companion-to-samuel-beckett/oclc/1125293417), edited by Dirk Van Hulle (Cambridge University Press, 2015) contains the essay "*Malone*, *Malone Dies*, *The Unnamable*: The Novel Reshaped" by Angela Moorjani.